# PayPal Receipts Showing a Pending (Incomplete Transaction)

Tags: joomla, paypal, ipn

The confirmation is returned from Paypal and the Thank You page is displayed, however the db still shows Incomplete Transaction, and confirmation email is not sent.  I'm pretty sure this issue was introduced by an update in Feb 2016.  Anyone found a resolution yet please? (Joomla 3.5.1 currently)
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The guys on the core team have done a tremendous job in resolving this issue in v 4.7.13 - you can refer to the following JIRA ticket for details: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18483

Hope this helps!
Tamar